# Condensing output into single line

Tags: c++

I'm working on an assignment that allows a user to enter integers (up to 20 entries) and displays a list of odd entries and even entries, when '0' is entered.  The assignment requires the user to input a single integer per line.

I have managed to extract and segregate the odd and even entries, however the assignment requires that the odds be displayed on a single line, and the evens on another single line below that.

For example, if the user entered integers 1-9:

```
Odds: 1 3 5 7 9
Evens: 2 4 6 8
```

Currently, it returns:

```
Even: 2
Even: 4
Even: 6
Odd: 1
Odd: 3
Odd: 5
etc...
```

I am hoping that my program will even allow this, but I suspect the problem lies in the way I have set up the loops.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isEven(int x) {
    if ((x%2) == 0) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}

int main(){

    const int x = 20;
    int list[x];
    int counter;

    cout<<"Enter up to 20 integers or press 0 to display list"<<endl;

    for (counter=0; counter<x; counter++) { //main loop

        cout<<"Enter number: ";
        cin>>list[counter];

        if (list[counter]==0) {
            for (int i =0; i<counter; i++) {
                if (isEven(list[i])==true) {
                cout<<"Even: "<<list[i];
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j<counter; j++) {
                if (isEven(list[j])==false) {
                cout<<"Odd: "<<list[j];
                }
            }
        break;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Move the "Even: " and "Odd: " portions outside the loops so they print only once. Will that fix what you are facing?

Comment: A little [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should go a long way to help you understand what's wrong with your current code. Hopefully it should also give you some idea how to solve it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Split input and output to separate loops:

```
for (counter=0; counter<x; counter++) {
    // input
}
for (counter=0; counter<x; counter++) {
    // output
}
```

Print labels before going through each value and use `\n` to print a newline:

```
        cout << "Even: ";
        for (int i =0; i<counter; i++) {
            if (isEven(list[i])==true) {
            cout << list[i];
            }
        }
        cout << "\nOdd: ";
        for (int j = 0; j<counter; j++) {
            if (isEven(list[j])==false) {
            cout << list[j];
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
```